# I want to play a quicktime movie in my app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

I would like to play a quicktime movie in my app, can it be possible in webview or in any other view, my only resource is my quicktime link.

Comment: Is this a url or just a local file?

Comment: it does not matter, url I guess

Answer (score 1):

I already used a little trick to play audio files from URL in QuickTime. I guess it can work for movies files too. Here is my code :

```
NSString *url = @"http://my_url.com/my_movie_path/";
UIWebView* tempAudioPlayer = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, 0)]; 
[tempAudioPlayer loadHTMLString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<iframe frameborder=\"0\" width=\"0\" height=\"0\" src=\"%@\"></iframe>", url] baseURL:nil];
[self addSubview:tempAudioPlayer];
```

I first create a UIWebView which will not be displayed. Then I `loadHTMLString` a `<iframe>` in it, with the URL of my file as the `src` value. And I add it to my view. Quicktime appears immediately.

Comment: So why did you validate the answer ? Could you post an example of your movie URL ?

Comment: Have a look at my edit. I made a mistake in my code : "http://" was written twice.

Comment: hmm.. I loaded a URLRequest of the webview

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *url = "http://my_url.com/my_movie_path/AAA.mov";
UIWebView *tempAudioPlayer;
[tempAudioPlayer loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]]];
```